# Set timeout to iosSlider autoslide

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-plugins, slider

I need to make some pause between finish all home animation and first turning of slide.

[FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3sszZ/) - as you can see, the appearance of the menu and scroll of the first slide is occurs simultaneously.

How can I finish all animation and then after 1 , 2 seconds activate the autoslide.

Tried this:

```
// HOME IOSSLIDER SETTINGS
  $('.iosSlider').iosSlider({
    snapToChildren: true,
    scrollbarDrag: true,
    scrollbarContainer: '.iosSlider',
    scrollbarMargin: 0,
    scrollbarHeight: '10px',
    scrollbarBorderRadius: 1,
    scrollbarOpacity: 1
  });

  // set initial position of slider scrollbar
  var x = $('#home-wrap').height() + 10 + 'px';
  $('.scrollbarBlock1').css('top', x );

  //
  $('#logo-hello-big').fadeIn(1500, function(){
    $('#logo-hello-small').fadeIn(1500);

    function logoHide(){
      $('#logo-hello-big, #logo-hello-small').fadeOut(1500);
    };
    setTimeout(logoHide, 2500);

    function menuShow(){
      $('#menu-wrap').animate({bottom:'0'},500);
      $('#logo-holder').animate({top:'0'},500);
      var z = $('#home-wrap').height() - 70 + 'px'; 
      $('.scrollbarBlock1').animate({top: z },500);
    };
    setTimeout(menuShow, 4000);

    // here i tried to add autoSlide: true to slider settings after finishing of all animation
    function autoplayActivate(){  
      $('.iosSlider').iosSlider({
      autoSlide: true
      });
    };
    setTimeout(autoplayActivate, 4000);


  });
```